# SQL Server : display data/column from SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data that holds a bunch of HTML attributes.

For example: `'<HTML><BODY></BODY></HTML>'`

I would like to be able to write a `SELECT` statement that can grab those values, but display them modified.

So instead of displaying

```
'<HTML><BODY>DATA</BODY></HTML>'
```

I want to show:

```
'<HTML>
<BODY>DATA</BODY>
</HTML>'
```

Essentially, breaking out each one to a new line, based on finding a '>' value, without modifying the data.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. I tried looking into `STRING_SPLIT`, but I can't get that to apply from the `SELECT` part.

Any suggestions where I look?

Edit 2/22 - it appears `REPLACE` gets me further, but when reviewing this more, it may not be possible.

How would SQL know to break out to a new line when the ending HTML tag appears?

It's almost like I need to use a RegEx in here...

```
REPLACE(TD.DefDetails, '</', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '</') As DefDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

STRING_SPLIT can split a single column into multiple rows.   STRING_SPLIT does require SQL Server Version 2016+.  The following snippet does show an example for this scenario.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DECLARE @HTMLString AS VARCHAR(100) = '<HTML><BODY></BODY></HTML>';

SELECT *
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@HTMLString,'>');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2203b93ef5dcdd4c1747e2089b5dcaf5)

You can achieve it in this way

```
SELECT REPLACE('<HTML><BODY></BODY></HTML>', '>', '>'+ CHAR(13))
```

Or if you want to get the value into rows, you can do this way.

```
Select value + '>' 
from STRING_SPLIT('<HTML><BODY></BODY></HTML>', '>')
where value <> ''
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Mrbobdou

Comment: Thanks, this actually did answer my question, but I realize my end goal needs to keep the <BODY> and </BODY> on the same line. So I'm not entirely sure how this will be possible without leveraging some kind of RegEx...

Answer (score 0):

Actually appears this is done using REPLACE.

```
REPLACE(Table.DefDetails, '>', '>'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) As DefDetails
```